# Solr Query Performance on Large Number Of Dynamic Fields

Tags: solr

This question is a follow-up question to my previous question: [Is child documents in solr anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57197574/is-child-documents-in-solr-anti-pattern)

I am creating a new question on dynamic field performance as I did not find any recent relevant posts on this topic and felt it deserved a separate question here.

I am aware that dynamic fields are treated as static fields and performance-wise both are similar.

Further, from what I have read, in terms of memory, dynamic fields are not efficient. Say, if a document has 100 fields and another has 1000(max number of fields in the collection), Apache Solr will allocate the memory block to support all 1000 fields for all the documents in the collection.

I have a requirement where I have 6-7 fields that could be part of child documents and each parent document could have up to 300 child documents. Which means each parent document could have ~2000 fields.

What will be the performance impact on queries when we have such a large number of fields in the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That really depends on *what you want to do with the field* and what the definition of these fields are. With `docValues`, most earlier issues with memory usage for sparse fields (i.e. fields that only have values in a small number of the total number of documents) are solved.

Also, you can usually rewrite those dynamic fields to a single multiValued field for filtering instead of filtering on each field (i.e. `common_field:field_prefix_value` where `common_field` contains the values you want to filter on prefixed with a field name / unique field id).

Anyway, the last case is that it'll depend on how many documents you have in total. If you only have 1000 documents, it won't be an issue in any way. If you have a million, it used to be - depending on what you needed those dynamic fields for. These days it really isn't an issue, and I'd start out with the naive, direct solution and see if that works properly for your use case. It's rather hard to say without knowing exactly what these fields will contain, what the use case for the fields are, what they'll be used for and the query profile of your application.

Also consider using a "side car" index if necessary, i.e. a special index with duplicated data from your main index to solve certain queries or query requirements. You pick which index to search based on the use case, and then return the appropriate data to the user.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We have around 100k documents and on those docs, 1-2 dynamic fields will be used for filter query and 1(price) field will be used for range faceting and range based filter queries. So we will have 2-3 fields with docValues

Comment: That should work fine. What we previously had issues with in regards to sparse fields were pre-4.0 and sorting. In those cases a cache list were built and sized for the whole set of documents for each field (and that field cache couldn't be disabled/sized/etc.), instead of just for those that had the field present. `docValues` greatly helps with sorting, so even that shooouldn't be an issue any longer (and Solr is far more mature today than pre-4.0). Seeing as you can adjust the filter cache manually, you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks! just a correction on my previous comment, when I said `1-2` and `2-3` dynamic fields, I meant prefix names, So, the actual number of fields would be multiplied by close to 300. Does that change anything?
Thanks for the update on the sparse field issue update, I wasn't aware that was fixed :)

Comment: It isn't really fixed per-se, but `docValues` works around the problem in my experience. We hit issues with about 2.5k of dynamic fields, but it took some time before it became apparent - and restarting Solr to clear out the field cache made stuff work fine again. We didn't spend any time adjusting the JVM memory at that time, so you can probably make it a lot further these days before any issues arise. I think you'll be fine.